# A biconnected bipartite non-Hamiltonian graph?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

So I'm trying to find a biconnected bipartite non-Hamiltonian graph and here's what I found:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3kHT.png
There's no Hamiltonian cycle and we can split the vertices into two even parts. So does this graph fit all the properties and if it does then how can I prove it because I'm having trouble proving that it's biconnected.

Comment: The fact that each vertex lies on a cycle is not enough to prove that the graph is "biconnected"? What is your definition of "biconnected"? And why isn't $K_{2,3}$ an example of a biconnected bipartite non-Hamiltonian graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not $(\{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,5\}, \{3,5\}, \{4,5\}\})$?  (This is $K_{2,3}$.)  Biconnected is easy enough to see.  The bipartition is $\{\{1,5\},\{2,3,4\}\}$.  For Hamiltonian cycles, starting at $1$, you complete a cycle and then must leave $1$ to reach the remaining vertex and can never return to $1$.  The analysis of $5$ is the same.  For $2$, you must first go to $1$ (or $5$ which is the same under the relabelling "$1$" $\leftrightarrow$ "$5$"), then the analysis from $1$ applies.

Comment: Even simpler, a bipartite graph can't have a cycle of odd length, in particular, of length $5.$